# Draw arc like progressbar with touch options for Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-progressbar

i have got some problem with my own progressbar.
When i click on dot they catch me.
I try do it something like that:

[image: my own progressbar with touch option]

here is code:

```
    package test.pionas.myapplication;

    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.TypedArray;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
    import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
    import android.graphics.RectF;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;

    public class PioArcCircle extends View {
        private static final String TAG = PioArc.class.getSimpleName();
        private static int INVALID_PROGRESS_VALUE = -1;
        private float mThickness = 50f; // thickness of line
        private int mRotate = 0; // rotate circle in degrees
        private Paint mCircleBgPaint;
        private int mCircleEndAngle = 270; // end arc
        private int mCircleStartAngle = 0; // start arc
        private int mCircleSweepAngle = 0; // actualy arc
        private RectF mCircleOuterBounds;
        private int mCircleBgColor = Color.RED; // color of circle

        private Paint mCirclePaint; // progressbar
        private int mCircleColor = Color.BLUE; // color of progressbar

        private Paint mEraserPaint;
        private RectF mCircleInnerBounds;
        private int mEraserColor = Color.YELLOW; // background color of circle
        private boolean mEraserInnerBackground = false; // eraser background inner circle

        private Bitmap mBitmap;
        private Canvas mCanvas;

        private float mMinValue = 0; // min progressbar value
        private float mMaxValue = 100; // max progressbar value
        private float mProgressSweep = 0; // start progressbar value
        private boolean mEnabled; // draw dot
        private float mDotSize; // dot size
        private Paint mCircleThumbPaint;
        private float mTranslateX; // center circle (axis X)
        private float mTranslateY; // center circle (axis Y)
        private boolean mTouchInside; // touch inside circle can change position on progress
        private float mTouchIgnoreRadius;
        private int mArcRadius;
        private int mThumbXPos;
        private int mThumbYPos;
        private OnPioArcCircleChangeListener mOnPioArcCircleChangeListener;
        public PioArcCircle(Context context) {
            super(context);
            initDefaultValue(context, 0, null);
        }

        public PioArcCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            initDefaultValue(context, 0, attrs);
        }

        public PioArcCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
            initDefaultValue(context, defStyleAttr, attrs);
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        public PioArcCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
            initDefaultValue(context, defStyleAttr, attrs);
        }

        private void initDefaultValue(Context context, int defStyleAttr, AttributeSet attrs) {

            if (attrs != null) {
                TypedArray typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                        attrs,
                        R.styleable.PioArcCircle,
                        defStyleAttr, 0);

                this.mThickness = typedArray.getFloat(R.styleable.PioArcCircle_thickness1, this.mThickness);
                this.mRotate = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.PioArcCircle_rotate, this.mRotate);
                this.mCircleSweepAngle = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.PioArcCircle_circleSweepAngle, this.mCircleSweepAngle);
                this.mCircleEndAngle = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.PioArcCircle_circleEndAngle, this.mCircleEndAngle);
                this.mCircleStartAngle = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.PioArcCircle_circleStartAngle, this.mCircleStartAngle);
                this.mCircleBgColor = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.PioArcCircle_circleBgColor, this.mCircleBgColor);
                this.mEraserColor = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.PioArcCircle_eraserColor, this.mEraserColor);
                this.mEraserInnerBackground = typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.PioArcCircle_eraserInnerBackground, this.mEraserInnerBackground);
                this.mMinValue = typedArray.getFloat(R.styleable.PioArcCircle_minValue, this.mMinValue);
                this.mMaxValue = typedArray.getFloat(R.styleable.PioArcCircle_maxValue, this.mMaxValue);
                this.mEnabled = typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.PioArcCircle_enable, this.mEnabled);
                this.mDotSize = typedArray.getFloat(R.styleable.PioArcCircle_dotSize, this.mDotSize);
                this.mTouchInside = typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.PioArcCircle_touchInside, this.mTouchInside);

                this.mCircleColor = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.PioArcCircle_circleBgColor, this.mCircleColor);

            }
            mCircleBgPaint = new Paint();
            mCircleBgPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mCircleBgPaint.setColor(mCircleBgColor);

            mCirclePaint = new Paint();
            mCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mCirclePaint.setColor(mCircleColor);

            mEraserPaint = new Paint();
            mEraserPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mEraserPaint.setColor(mEraserColor);
            if (mEraserInnerBackground) {
                mEraserPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
            }

            mCircleThumbPaint = new Paint();
            mCircleThumbPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mCircleThumbPaint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            if (w != oldw || h != oldh) {
                mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            }

            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            updateBounds();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            int min = Math.min(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, parentHeight);
            this.setTouchInSide(this.mTouchInside);
            super.onMeasure(min, min);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            mCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            mCanvas.drawArc(mCircleOuterBounds, (mCircleStartAngle + mRotate), (mCircleEndAngle - mCircleStartAngle), true, mCircleBgPaint);

            if (mCircleSweepAngle - mRotate > 0f) {
                mCanvas.drawArc(mCircleOuterBounds, (mCircleStartAngle + mRotate), (mCircleSweepAngle - mRotate), true, mCirclePaint);
            }

            mCanvas.drawOval(mCircleInnerBounds, mEraserPaint);

            if (mEnabled) {
                mThumbXPos = (int) (mTranslateX + (mArcRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((double) this.mCircleSweepAngle))));
                mThumbYPos = (int) (mTranslateY + (mArcRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians((double) this.mCircleSweepAngle))));
                mCanvas.drawCircle(mThumbXPos, mThumbYPos, mThickness, mCircleThumbPaint);
            }

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        }

        private void updateBounds() {
            if (this.getPaddingLeft() < (mThickness / 2)) {
                this.setPadding((int) (mThickness / 2), this.getPaddingTop(), this.getPaddingRight(), this.getPaddingBottom());
            }

            mCircleOuterBounds = new RectF(0 + this.getPaddingLeft(), 0 + this.getPaddingLeft(), getWidth() - this.getPaddingLeft(), getHeight() - this.getPaddingLeft());
            mCircleInnerBounds = new RectF(
                    mCircleOuterBounds.left + mThickness,
                    mCircleOuterBounds.top + mThickness,
                    mCircleOuterBounds.right - mThickness,
                    mCircleOuterBounds.bottom - mThickness);

            this.mTranslateX = mCircleOuterBounds.centerX();
            this.mTranslateY = mCircleOuterBounds.centerY();

            this.mArcRadius = (int) (mTranslateX - this.getPaddingLeft() - (mThickness / 2));
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (this.mEnabled) {
                this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case 0:
                        this.onStartTrackingTouch();
                        this.updateOnTouch(event);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        this.onStopTrackingTouch();
                        this.setPressed(false);
                        this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        this.updateOnTouch(event);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        this.onStopTrackingTouch();
                        this.setPressed(false);
                        this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                }

                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void setTouchInSide(boolean isEnabled) {
            int thumbHalfheight = (int) (mThickness / 2);
            int thumbHalfWidth = (int) (mThickness / 2);
            this.mTouchInside = isEnabled;
            if (this.mTouchInside) {
                this.mTouchIgnoreRadius = (float) this.mArcRadius / 4.0F;
            } else {
                this.mTouchIgnoreRadius = (float) (this.mArcRadius - Math.min(thumbHalfWidth, thumbHalfheight));
            }
        }

        private void updateOnTouch(MotionEvent event) {
            boolean ignoreTouch = this.ignoreTouch(event.getX(), event.getY());
            if (!ignoreTouch) {
                this.setPressed(true);
                this.mProgressSweep = (float) this.getTouchDegrees(event.getX(), event.getY());
                this.updateProgress((int) this.mProgressSweep);
            }
        }

        private double getTouchDegrees(float xPos, float yPos) {
            double angle = (int) (Math.atan2(yPos - mTranslateY, xPos - mTranslateX) * 180 / Math.PI);
            if (angle < 0) {
                angle += 360;
            }
            float x = xPos - this.mTranslateX;
            float y = yPos - this.mTranslateY;
            angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2((double) y, (double) x) + 1.5707963267948966D - Math.toRadians((double) this.mRotate));
            if (angle < 0.0D) {
                angle += 360.0D;
            }

            angle -= (double) this.mCircleStartAngle;
            return angle;
        }

        private boolean ignoreTouch(float xPos, float yPos) {
            boolean ignore = false;
            double touchRadius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xPos - this.mTranslateX, 2) + Math.pow(yPos - this.mTranslateY, 2));

            if (this.mTouchInside && touchRadius > this.mArcRadius) {
                ignore = true;
            } else {
                if ((touchRadius > (this.mArcRadius + (this.mThickness / 2))) ||
                        (touchRadius < (this.mArcRadius - (this.mThickness / 2)))) {
                    ignore = true;
                }
            }
            return ignore;
        }

        private void onStartTrackingTouch() {
            if (this.mOnPioArcCircleChangeListener != null) {
                this.mOnPioArcCircleChangeListener.onStartTrackingTouch(this);
            }

        }

        private void onStopTrackingTouch() {
            if (this.mOnPioArcCircleChangeListener != null) {
                this.mOnPioArcCircleChangeListener.onStopTrackingTouch(this);
            }
        }


        private void updateProgress(int progress) {
            if (progress != INVALID_PROGRESS_VALUE) {
                if (this.mOnPioArcCircleChangeListener != null) {
                    this.mOnPioArcCircleChangeListener.onProgressChanged(this);
                }

                mCircleSweepAngle = progress;
                this.invalidate();
            }
        }

        public OnPioArcCircleChangeListener getmOnPioArcCircleChangeListener() {
            return mOnPioArcCircleChangeListener;
        }

        public void setmOnPioArcCircleChangeListener(OnPioArcCircleChangeListener mOnPioArcCircleChangeListener) {
            this.mOnPioArcCircleChangeListener = mOnPioArcCircleChangeListener;
        }

        public interface OnPioArcCircleChangeListener {
            void onProgressChanged(PioArcCircle var1);

            void onStartTrackingTouch(PioArcCircle var1);

            void onStopTrackingTouch(PioArcCircle var1);
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <com.test.myapplication.PioArcCircle
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
        pioarccircle:circleColor="@color/colorAccent"
        pioarccircle:enable="true"
        pioarccircle:minValue="50.0"
        pioarccircle:rotate="135"
        pioarccircle:thickness1="100" />
```

First problem:
[image: first problem]

How i can create a few colors of progress?

Thanks for help.

Comment: There are libraries don't you like to use a one?

Comment: I can't find the library with the features which i need

Comment: Try this library 
https://github.com/chiralcode/Android-Color-Picker

You can customize it 

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9s0u.png

Comment: Thanks for help but i still looking for to draw arc with touchEvent options...

Comment: Please share a full demo source code with us, so atleast we learners can learn... :)